# React Native AWS S3 upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm using [react-native-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) and [react-native-s3-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-s3-upload) to upload images to s3 bucket.

```
 RNS3.put(file, AWSOptions)
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 201) {
           throw new Error('Failed to upload image to S3');
         }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
         console.log('Error', JSON.stringify(error));
         throw error;
    });
```

and I get a response like this without image been uploaded.

```
Object {
  "headers": Object {},
  "status": 0,
  "text": "Stream Closed",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative module ([aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)) to upload files to the S3 bucket with RN 62 version.

Also, I have used [base64-arraybuffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer) and [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0) modules well.

```
const s3bucket = new S3({
      accessKeyId: XXXXXXXXXX,
      secretAccessKey: XXXXXXXXXXXX,
      Bucket: XXXXXXXXX,
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
    });
    let contentType = 'image/jpeg';
    let contentDeposition = 'inline;filename="' + file.name + '"';

    const base64 = await fs.readFile(file.uri, 'base64');

    const arrayBuffer = decode(base64);

    s3bucket.createBucket(() => {
      const params = {
        Bucket: XXXXXXXXXXX,
        Key: file.name,
        Body: arrayBuffer,
        ContentDisposition: contentDeposition,
        ContentType: contentType,
      };
      s3bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error in callback');
          console.log(err);
          setSpinner(false);
        }
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data.Location);
        setImageUrl(data.Location);
        setSpinner(false);
      });
    });
```

Comment: hey @chameera Dulanga how did you use react-native-fs, it give me an error upon reading file. I have tried
const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
then usingRNFS like you did with fs 
`this package itself specifies a **main** module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\Dell\Documents\apps\audiomessage\node_modules\react-native-fs\FS.common.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:`

Comment: @MuhammadEhteshamAnwar Complete guide is in this article https://medium.com/better-programming/upload-images-to-aws-s3-in-react-native-0-60-f20c547a963c

But Unfortunately, I couldn't really think of a reason for your error.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same issue with a similar library called react-native-aws3.
It seems related to the new React Native version 0.62.2, because I've tried to upgrade today (my previous version was 0.61.5) and that library worked before.

I don't know if both libraries use a common API which now is broken in the new RN, but I suggest you to downgrade in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried for days to fix it. This is what I came up with.

Make sure you follow the amplify guide and set up `amplify init`, `amplify add auth` and then do `amplify push`

Then do `amplify add storage` and follow the guide here (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js). Then copy this code.

````
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './src/aws-exports'
// import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
// Might need to switch line 7 to awsconfig 
Amplify.configure(config)

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';


function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    
    console.log(result) 

    async function pathToImageFile(data) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(data);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        await Storage.put(`customer/images`, blob, {
          contentType: 'image/jpeg', // contentType is optional
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error uploading file:', err);
      }
    }
    
    // later
    
    pathToImageFile(result.uri);
  }


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      <Button title="Upload image" onPress={() => {alert(image)}} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default withAuthenticator(App)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `RN >= 0.62`

You can either roll back to version `< 0.62` or you can follow what I did.

I solved it by commenting out line number 43 in `android/app/src/debug/java/**/ReactNativeFlipper.java`

```js
NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
  new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
      // builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin)); <---- This line
    }
  });
client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
client.start();
```

You will need to rebuild the app after doing this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 upload is a powerful service provided by [React Native AWS](https://www.instamobile.io/mobile-development/react-native-aws-amplify/) amplify. The issue here might be caused by the React Native version or improper configuration of the package. You can check some amazing articles out there that will definitely help you integrate React Native AWS amplify properly based on your project configurations and make the AWS S3 upload working properly as well.