# Expo (React Native) S3 image upload returns "Stream Closed" using XHR

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo, xmlhttprequest

After updating Expo to the latest SDK 49 (React Native v0.72.1) and trying to upload the image to AWS S3 bucket using XHR, it returns the error "Stream Closed".

Image upload was working fine with Expo SDK 48 and earlier versions.

The Code:

```
function makeRequest(method, url, uploadData) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                resolve({
                    status: this.status,
                    responseText: this.responseText,
                });
            } else {
                console.warn(
                    'status -->',
                    this.status,
                    'responseText -->',
                    this.responseText
                );
                reject(
                    new Error({
                        status: this.status,
                        responseText: this.responseText,
                    })
                );
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            console.log(
                'status -->',
                this.status,
                '; responseText -->',
                this.responseText
            );
            reject(
                new Error({
                    status: this.status,
                    responseText: xhr.responseText,
                    response: xhr.response,
                })
            );
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        xhr.send({
            uri: uploadData.uri,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            name: uploadData.fileName,
        });
    });
}
```

When the user wants to upload an image, first the App sends a request to the server and gets a pre-signed URL, and the image gets uploaded from the client side. This has worked until updating Expo to SDK 49.

This problem is not new. There were similar issues reported: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267222/react-native-s3-image-upload-returns-stream-closed-using-xhr)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387293/react-native-aws-s3-upload) with RN versions 0.62 and 0.63. However, none of the answers in these questions is applicable to my code (except to revert the previous version that worked). Moreover, as this problem has not been reported in the last 2/3 years, and a few RN versions were released in the meantime, I suppose this issue is actually a new one.